# Continuity of bivariate function

Tags: functions, continuity

Define $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y) = 0 \end{cases}$

Then $f = 1/2$ along the curve $y = x^2$, but $f$ has no limit at $(0,0)$ along the line $y = x$. Is $f$ continuous at the origin? What's the reasoning for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Approach along $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the limit at a given point would exist, then it should be attained along any sequence converging to that given point.

As it is not the case [add your conclusion here], so in particular your function cannot be continuous at that point.